# horizontal scrolling images issue using <ul> and <li>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal scrolling of images as can be seen in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PJGGC/) fiddle.
For some reason I can't get the images to stack in one line and they always go to the next line, which is not what I want. How do I create a horizontal scrolling images without any plugin?

Here's my css setup:

```
.admin-shop-images {
    list-style: none;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}

.admin-shop-images li {
    background-color: #f3efea;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.admin-shop-images li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.admin-shop-images li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You could do something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/q6BBZ/)**... i'm positive there is a better way to achieve this though. I just can't seem to think of it at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/PJGGC/9/)

I placed the content inside the `div` and in the css i gave this

```
  #ImageContainer{
    width:200px;
overflow-x:scroll;   
    height:140px;
overflow-y:hidden;       
}
```

With this you can change the width of the div to shrink the entire container size
Check for smaller div size [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/PJGGC/10/)

Answer (score 2):

It's the floating left that causes the problem.  If you change that to `display: inline-block` and then add `white-space: nowrap` to the `<ul>` they'll scroll.  Like this:

```
.admin-shop-images {
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 800px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.admin-shop-images li {
  background-color: #f3efea;
  margin-right: 25px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PJGGC/8/

Comment: Very nice ! :) I didnt notice that

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/7jmj4/2/)

> IT wll need a container div which will be of fix size and inner ul will have width more than that of div.

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul class="admin-shop-images clearfix">
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c21feee5b4911e3a4d80e849028c7eb_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/d6057b165b4d11e39ba70a3e328747b8_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/4f8270305b4d11e389310e362925b2d5_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/8d3a2c085b4b11e3ab4c12ca54d8f342_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/382915805b4b11e3b5c00e9e2a89cc53_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/e0596b165b4a11e39c4d0ee0497810b2_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/07ca8a4a5b6411e3a1741240743416c5_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/c6d561485b6011e398920ee3b99546be_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/441215805b6011e3bc620eb29dbbaea3_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage6.s3.amazonaws.com/8e7faf6a5b5b11e380d712128faa8e82_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com/87c3a7605b8a11e3a33e1264bd1e5b12_5.jpg)"></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 800px;
    height:150px
}
.admin-shop-images {
    list-style: none;
    width: 1500px;
}
.admin-shop-images li {
    background-color: #f3efea;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
    float: left;
}
.admin-shop-images li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.admin-shop-images li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this open source.  [simply scroll v2](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal_manual.html) Hope this helps someone. This script can be customised or you could learn from it.